# How can display text on the right side here?

Tags: html, css

I have this site: [link](http://capuano.ch/?page_id=14)

Checkout page of this site I want to display a text in the right form "phone" like a picture below.

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/207m3jd.jpg]

This is code for form:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-last validate-required validate-phone woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field" id="billing_phone_field">
    <label for="billing_phone" class="">Phone <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" placeholder="" value="">
</p>
```

I tried to modify the code so

```
<p class="form-row form-row-last validate-required validate-phone woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field" id="billing_phone_field"><label for="billing_phone" class="">Phone <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" placeholder="" value="">
<p style="float: left;">text</p></p>
```

Do you know how I can arrange text right there and why not go?

EDIT:pass:dgdesign

Comment: You're website is password protected. Either post the password or unprotect it so people can see it.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks like Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, your website is password protected. Please remove the authentication.

Comment: sorry,in put the pass

Comment: The link http://capuano.ch/?page_id=14 redirects to http://capuano.ch/?page_id=13 And where is your form? Can you paste your complete code?

Comment: form is in a checkout page.Add a product and go to checkout page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put an [inline element](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) in the right, for example a `small` tag:

```
<p>
<label for="billing_phone">
      Phone <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>
</label>
<input 
      type="text" 
      class="input-text " 
      name="billing_phone" 
      id="billing_phone" 
      placeholder="" value="">
    <label for="billing_phone" class="">
        <small class="some-class"> Phone </small>
    </label>
</p>
```

and add some padding:

```
small.some-class {  padding: 20px; }
```

[Demo here](https://jsbin.com/cobegad/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: That puts the text under the `<input>`.

Comment: So, add more width to the container and /  or reduce the width of the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `style="position: relative;"` to `<p id="billing_phone">`

And right after that line:

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" placeholder="" value="">
```

Try this:

```
<span style="position: absolute;bottom: 14%; left: 100%">Text goes here</span>
```

Hope it helps! :)